# 413 Request Entity Too Large in Nginx and Amazon ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There are a lot of answers to this problem ([question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030736/how-to-resolve-error-413-request-entity-too-large-in-nginx-and-amazon-elasticbea) [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610972/aws-elastic-beanstalk-request-entity-too-large-413)) but this solution that should work, doesn't work for me:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        client_max_body_size 50M;
```

I have checked the status and contents of this created file via ssh and its correct. I also have tried other values and restarted the server multiple times.

```
client_max_body_size 0;
```

or

```
http {
   client_max_body_size 50M;
}
```

This values do not work either.

it just wont work, even with "just" a 6mb image. it work with smaller images around size of 0.5mb. It's a RoR app with "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.8.0 running Ruby 2.5 (Puma)". The instance size is t2.micro.

Comment: Can you post the output of `nginx -T` on your EBS machine?

Comment: @TarunLalwani https://pastebin.com/25kmG4Bb here you go

Comment: The config seems to applied, can you reload the nginx service through SSH and see if that helps. Also can you show the error logs of nginx

Comment: i have restarted the servers via ebs web console and even rebuild the entire environment, multiple times, the error.log doesn't show any problems regarding this issue. maybe its because this ebs env lives behind a cloudfront cdn?

Comment: That's a important details missing from the question as such. But looking at the limits https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-general it should still be in safe zone

Comment: Are you sure that your conf file is being loaded? The Passenger platform does not - I had to add `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` to `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config_healthd.erb`. The Puma platform might be different, however.

Comment: yes i tried to add a syntax error to the file and the system said it wont load it. maybe the nignx is not restarting if you restart from the ebs web console

Answer (score 6):

Try this. It worked for me:

```
content: |
    server {
        ***your server configuration***

        location / {
             client_max_body_size 100M;
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this may be the answer, please add additional detail and explanation of why it is the answer.

Comment: Here are some sample configs, among which is also one with `client_max_body_size ` in it. Hope it helps give some context. https://gist.github.com/nateware/3988974