# 413 Request Entity Too Large AWS Elastic Beanstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, rest, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have uploaded springboot Rest APi over elastic beanstack, as a WAR file. Rest API is actually uploading file here is my code

```
@PostMapping(value = "/post")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('WRITE')")
public ResponseEntity<?> createPost(@RequestParam String postData,
                                    @RequestPart(value = "attachments", required = false)
                                            MultipartFile attachments) {
    PostEntity postEntity = getPostEntity(postData);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(postService.createPost(postEntity, attachments), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

its working fine in local enviroment, I am able to upload file up 50 MB (so for I tried). But after deploying on AWS cloud, its giving me Request Entity Too Large (413) error.

What Tried so far:

I created src/main/resources/.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf  file and  inside that I have put

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

But it didn't work somehow.

I have also tried this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610972/aws-elastic-beanstalk-request-entity-too-large-413):

If anyone has any suggestion please share suggestion here.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm stuck with this :(

Comment: @Mohammedshebin you have to increase the  body size of nginx config, let me search steps for you I have noted it somewhere, Because its not right now in top of my head

Answer (score 1):

I followed below blog :

https://medium.com/@robin.srimal/how-to-fix-a-413-request-entity-too-large-error-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-ac2bb15f244d

> sudo vim ngnix.conf